# Career in Mathematics as an Electrical Engineer

Tags: mathematical-physics, education, research

I am a university freshman with major in Electrical Engineering. My passion is pure math(topology, group theory etc). During my first semester I noticed that our math classes are not rigorous at all, focusing on approximations and practical purposes. My goal is to work on theoretical math research or mathematical Physics. Should I stay in engineering (and follow it with a math post-graduate) or switch to math major? In other words, is it possible to be applicable for research with a masters degree in Electrical Engineering?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com